# The name 'model' does not exist in current context

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my view want to list all child entities:

```
@model Estimating.Models.Client

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
}

<h1>Details</h1>

<div>
    <h4>Client</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="row">
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ClientName)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ClientName)
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <dl>
        @foreach (var tender in model.Tenders)
        {
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => tender.TenderRef)
        </div>
        }
    </dl>
  
</div>
<div>
    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@Model.ClientId">Edit</a> |
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

But getting error on `model.Tenders` - The name 'model' does not exist in current context.
Why is that? I have defined `@model Estimating.Models.Client` in first row.

Here ClientController Details action:

```
// GET: Clients/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var client = await _context.Clients
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ClientId == id);
            if (client == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(client);
    }
```

Am I missing something in Controller to make it work?

Comment: That'd be `Model.Tenders` -> you didn't define `model` as in the other statements for it to be available

Comment: This was my first thought but Model.Tenders return exception as if no child entities exist, where these exist.

Comment: I highly doubt it's the case that those exist as you think. Can you show the relevant Action code please?

Comment: If your intention is to list all child, have you tried:
`
@foreach (var tender in Model.Tenders)
        {
        <div class="editor-label">
            @tender.TenderRef
        </div>
        }
`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto ClientController detail action added to main post.

Comment: `Model.Tenders return exception as if no child entities exist` What exception?

Comment: @JohnH System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the code you've shown, and your comments, you have two separate problems:

1. You're confusing the `@model` directive with accessing the instance of the model using `Model`
2. The `Tenders` property of your model is not initialised

Let's address point 1 first.

When you state `@model Estimating.Models.Client` at the top of your view, this is telling the view that it should expect to receive of a model of the *type* `Estimating.Models.Client`.

When you use `Model.Tenders` in a block of Razor code, you are stating you want to access the `Tenders` property of the *instance* of the model.

Finally, when you call a HTML helper such as `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ClientName)`, `model` is now the *name of a parameter in a lambda expression* that uses  the type of model. You can actually see this by hovering your mouse cursor over `DisplayNameFor`, and you'll see something like:

```
string IHtmlHelper<Estimating.Models.Client>.DisplayNameFor<string>(
    System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Estimating.Models.Client, string>> expression)
```

As this is an expression, the name of the parameter doesn't have to be `model`. You could write `@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.ClientName)` and it would do the same thing.

The point I'm trying to make, is that people get confused when first learning MVC because the word `model` is unfortunately overloaded to mean several different things in different contexts.

To summarise:

1. `@model type` at the top of a view is specifying the *type* of model the view expects
2. `Model` (uppercase 'M') is referring to the *instance* of the model
3. `model` in a call such as `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Foo)` is the *name of a parameter in a lambda expression* and can equally be called with `@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.ClientName)` - the name `model` here is irrelevant

Back to your problem, you need to change your `foreach` loop to access the instance of the model via `Model`:

```
@foreach (var tender in Model.Tenders)
```

Now to point 2. You're most likely getting a `NullReferenceException` because you don't default initialise `Tenders` to something like `new List<Tender>()`.

Comment: Thank you for detail explanation. Really appreciated.

Comment: Tried to initialise Tenders in my Client model by following:  `public virtual ICollection<Tender> Tenders { get; set; } = new HashSet<Tender>();` but still no luck.

Comment: @Robert I think you should post a separate question then, as that is a different problem to the one described here. But, ideally, you should be able to figure out what the problem is if you put a breakpoint on the `return View(client);` line in your controller, start the debugger, and take a look at the data that is returned.

Answer (score 2):

Whole problem was in controller.
I have change it to:

```
var client = await _context.Clients
                .Where(m => m.ClientId == id)
                .Include(m => m.Tenders)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

It is necesarry to use `.Include(m => m.Tenders)` and then all works like a charm.